# Should I explicitly declare JavaScript version for Firefox? (UPDATED: How to support `let` on FF <=44)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, reactjs, babeljs

We've recently deployed JavaScript that uses the `let` statement.  This is not supported by Firefox [before 44](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) unless JavaScript1.7 or JavaScript1.8 is explicitly declared.

It strikes me as dangerous to use an explicit version declaration like `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.8">` to make `let` work on Firefox before 44.  I'm afraid of what the other browsers will do with this.

I understand that Firefox <44 is no longer supported by Mozilla but I would still like earlier browser versions to work if feasible and doesn't degrade the experience for users on current versions of FF, Chrome, Safari.

**EDIT**

I've concluded this is a [bad idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).  However, I am using Babel and Webpack and am now wondering how best to transpile our JavaScript to support FF <44.

Comment: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: @Tushar We use Babel to transpile to ECMA Script 5 ... which supports `let`

Comment: @AdamNelson `let` is not supported in ES5. Compare [the ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) with the [ES2015/ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-declarations-and-the-variable-statement). Babel will [transform `let` to `var` when using the `es2015` plugin.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20x%20%3D%2012%3B)

Comment: @MikeC Looks like you're right :-/  But then how can I properly strip the `let` statements out with Babel?

Comment: @AdamNelson Just use the `es2015` plugin. It will handle the conversion for you.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is supported in any version of Safari yet - [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=let)

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded this is a bad idea and am using Babel to transpile the JavaScript to support FF <44.